# Change Home Wallpaper

Tags: android, background, wallpaper

I have a application that have a lot of images, and I want to programmatically do a random chanegs of images on my phone backgroind. Is it possible to change wallpaper on android ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Use a WallpaperManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#setBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29).

Also, you'll have to include this permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```